# Как заставить главный поток ждать завершение другого потока в Firestore?

Tags: java, android-studio, firestore

Есть код, который берет информацию с БД Firestore:

```
DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("courses").document(id);
    documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                mCourse = new Course(documentSnapshot.getId(), documentSnapshot.get("name").toString(),
                        documentSnapshot.get("description").toString(), documentSnapshot.get("imagePath").toString());

            } else {
                Log.e("Firestore", "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
```

Следом за ним есть код, который сетит то, что получили в TextView:

```
void bind(Course course) {
        mCourse = course;
        mNameTextView.setText(mCourse.getName());
        mDescriptionTextView.setText(mCourse.getDescription());
        mProgressTextView.setText("Good");
    }
```

При запуске получаем NullPointerException, так как главный поток не ждет пока будет получена информация с Firestore, и соответственно сетит null в каждый TextView. Как можно заставить главный поток подождать получения информации?

Comment: Почему бы не вызвать метод `bind` из коллбэка `onComplete`?

Comment: bind у меня в адаптере для RecyclerView. У меня идет 2 обращения к бд, раз чтобы получить Course, второй раз получаю CourseItems для RecyclerView. Меня интересует именно приостановка главного потока, показать ProgressBar для ожидания результата, и когда будет получена информация - продолжить выполнение